# How to make the magento footer stick to the bottom?

Tags: css, magento

I'm trying to make the magento footer stick to the bottom on the page

http://stage.rayswesternwear.com/index.php/checkout/cart/

I've noticed that it's been a quite common issue with Magento.

There are plenty of solutions, I put it in here and it might help someone else: http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/solution-for-sticky-footer-for-magento-css/.

However, in this case, the above solution doesn't work.

I tried making the `main-container with`height:100%; padding-bottom:228px`and make the`footer-container`with`height:228px; margin-top:-228px`. I also tried clear the float.

The code I used is:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrapper {min-height: 100%;}

#main-container {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 228px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer-container {position: relative;
    margin-top: -228px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 228px;
    clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {/* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}
```

Both doesn't work for this page either.

Can anyone help me?

---

Thank you for all your answers. I solved it out by using:

**.page{ height: 100vh;}**

vh defines the height of the browser window. In this way the footer can be pushed down to the bottom in my case. Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: you should google it first with all the words you know before here

Comment: Thank you, I googled for 6 hours already. The only solution I figured out is to make the main-container with a fixed height (780px for example), or make the footer fixed, both are not ideal.

Comment: how about "css fixed footer"?

Comment: I tried to use the below coding, doesn't work here.                    html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrapper {min-height: 100%;}

#main-container {overflow:auto;
 padding-bottom: 228px;} 

#footer-container {position: relative;
 margin-top: -228px; /* negative value of footer height */
 height: 228px;
 clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before 
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Sticky Footer approach explained [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

It's a bit of an unwieldy solution, but provided you know the pixel height (228px for you), it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you Roberto, I tried this code in my localhost site, and it still doesn't work.